# SSRS - Specifying Values in Parameter Expression

Tags: reporting-services

Good afternoon -

I am working Visual Studio 2013, attempting to build one (1) parameter which has different values assigned to each option. I have created a data attribute which contains the following values:

- Active
- Error 1
- Error 2

I have specified the value in an expression for each option:

- All = "Active", "Error 1", "Error 2"
- Active = "Active"
- Errors Only = "Error 1", "Error 2"

The only option that works is the Active option. The others return no records.

How should I define the expression?

Any and All assistance is very much appreciated!

Comment: Specify the query conditions that you are using for your dataset. based on condition from your query, you should format these expressions

Comment: The data attribute is Error. The parameter name is @prmShow. I using the following in my Where clause: where Error IN (@prmShow).

Answer (score 0):

here is what you can do, you need to handle the query condition formatting and parameter values correctly. e.g. see below example.

**Dataset Query for Stored Procedure:**

*declare @renderType nvarchar(max)

declare @script nvarchar(max)

--set @renderType = 'txt,dump'

SELECT     @renderType =  REPLACE(@renderType , ',', ''',''')

set @script = 'select render_format, subscriber_id  from Sub_fact where  render_format in  (''' +@renderType+ ''')'

exec (@script);*

create stored procedure to do all this formatting correctly.

now in parameter properties this is what i have provided

[image]

this works perfectly for me. 
change your solution accordingly and it should work. respond with how it goes.